# Can't access data or copy data from XMLHttpRequest when Synchronous javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronous

How to access the information received from the `XMLHttpRequest` when `XMLHttpRequest` is synchronous?

```js
// JavaScript Pure and AJAX

    let data = [];
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let a = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //declear new obj in previus obj
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    let b = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    for (let i = 0; i < a.personInfo.length; i++) {
                        for (let j = 0; j < a.personInfo.length; j++){
                            if (a.personInfo[i].uid === b.additionalPersonInfo[j].uid) {
                                data[i] = Object.assign(a.personInfo[i], b.additionalPersonInfo[j])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/dc6cb50568fac72a4105", true);
            xhttp.send();
        } //end bulid in obj
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/177cea9c157de479d51b", true);
    xhttp.send();
    
    for (let o = 0; o < data.length; o++) {
          console.log(data[o]);
    }
```

I want access `data[]`

Comment: I would understand if you struggled getting _asynchronous_ data, but synchronous? Like, `a=2, how do I get the value of a?`  Also, `Ajax` and `synchronous` together is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: Synchronous mode for XMLHttpRequest is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing wrong without a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use synchronous AJAX. This is deprecated and will give a bad user experience. However, your ajax calls are not synchronous in the code you have provided.
2. Your inner loop should run through `b.additionalPersonInfo`. But you are running through `a.personalInfo` in the inner loop too.
3. You should push to your `data` array instead of trying to add data to yet non-existing elements.
4. Your data can only be accessed from within the callbacks - that is only after the data is really available.

```
    let data = [];

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            let a = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //declear new obj in previus obj

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    let b = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    for (let i = 0; i < a.personInfo.length; i++) {
                        for (let j = 0; j <  b.additionalPersonInfo.length; j++){
                            if (a.personInfo[i].uid === b.additionalPersonInfo[j].uid) {
                                data.push(Object.assign(a.personInfo[i], b.additionalPersonInfo[j]))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Here is the data -----> 
                    for (let o = 0; o < data.length; o++) {
                     console.log(data[o]);
                    }

                }
            };

            xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/dc6cb50568fac72a4105", true);
            xhttp.send();
        } //end bulid in obj
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/177cea9c157de479d51b", true);
    xhttp.send();
```